# Build HTML Table with JavaScript, row order

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, row

I am building a html table dynamically with Javascript; This is my html table:

```
<table class="ui-list" cellpadding="2" id = "tbl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Artikel ID</th>
                        <th>Artikelnr</th>
                        <th>Bezeichnung</th>
                        <th>Stk.</th>
                        <th><?php echo FW_HTML_Button::build('entfernen', array('onclick' => '' ,'id'=>'get_button')); ?></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Gesamt:</td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>Action:</td>
                    </tr>
                <!-- Fill with JS -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And this is how I fill it with rows:

```
         function addRow(tableID) {

                var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

                var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var element1 = obj[16][count]["id"]["article_id"];
                cell1.innerHTML = element1;

                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var element2 = obj[16][count]["id"]["article_no_internal"];
                cell2.innerHTML = element2;

                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var element3 = obj[16][count]["id"]["article_name_internal"];
                cell3.innerHTML = element3;

                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                cell4.innerHTML = obj[16][count]["stk"];;

                var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                var element4 = document.createElement("input");
                element4.type = "checkbox";
                cell5.appendChild(element4);

            }
```

It works just fine, my only problem is as you can see I already have a row in my html part, and I would like to put the new row, before the  row I created in html. For now it always puts the new rows after the row where is written 'gesamt' and 'action'. Is it possible to make this different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount - 1);
```

instead of

```
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
```

(Assuming, of course, that it is guarranteed that you'll always have that footer row in your table).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/hwSfG/

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery .prepend() function.
It inserts elements at the beginning of a parent element:
http://api.jquery.com/prepend/